# Loop vectorization

Tags: matlab, filtering, vectorization

I'm applying the filtering function in the frequency domain. Because I am working with large amounts of data, I want to vectorize the for loop shown below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
N = 2^nextpow2(length(signal));
Y = fft(signal,N);

df=1/(N*dt);
freq=0:df:N/2*df-df;
ff=freq./fccutlow;

H=zeros(1,length(N));
for i=2:length(ff)
   
    H(i)= sqrt((ff(i).^(2*nOrder)))./sqrt(((1+ff(i).^(2*nOrder))));
    Y(i)= Y(i).*H(i);
    Y(length(Y)-i+2)=Y(length(Y)-i+2).*H(i);
end
Y1= (real(ifft(Y,N)))';
Y1=Y1(1:length(signal));
filt_signal(1,:)=Y1;
```

Comment: What is `ff`? What is `Y`? Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

For vector arithmetic on whole matrix you do not need any indexing, only use [array operators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html), `.*`, `./`, `.^`. But when only a part of array is used as operand, you need to use one of [indexing methods](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). Keep in mind that all input and output ranges of arrays should be of [compatible sizes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html).

Check parentheses again, but it is something like this:

```
H = sqrt((ff.^(2*nOrder)))./sqrt(((1+ff.^(2*nOrder))));
Y= Y.*H;
Y(end-((1:length(ff))+2))=Y(end-((1:length(ff))+2)).*H;
```

**An example:** Note that it does not matter if the matrices themselves do not have same sizes, but the operands must have compatible sizes:

```
A = 1:4;         % 1x4
B = magic(3);    % 3x3
C = zeros(3, 1); % 3x1

C([1 3]) = A(3:end).*B(1:2, 2)';
```

Although in this example `A`, `B` and `C` have different sizes, but `A(3:end)` and `B(1:2, 2)'` are both 1 by 2 and the code runs with no problem. Try to run it and evaluate different parts of code to see how indexing works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Y array is double in size of H, returning an error for matrix multiplication.

Comment: @user3087937 added an example and couple of links  for further reading.